# Force Browser spell check onload in CKEditor 4?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have enabled Native/Browser Spell check on CKEditor 4 .
Problem is with SCAYT enabled it used to check the spelling of existing content in the editor on form load or editor onload . Now it doesn't give any red underline when I open the editor with some content having spelling mistakes . But Spell check works as I can see the spelling mistakes for any new content I write or paste into the editor .

Is there a way to force the native spell check on the existing content while loading the editor ?